# How do I constrain multiple variables with respect to one another when using scipy least_squares() to prevent sqrt() from returning imaginary number?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit an equation of the following form:

f(r) = B r^2/[1+sqrt(1-(A+1)(B r)^2)]

with A and B as the fitting coefficients. When I optimize, the argument inside the square root becomes negative so least_squares will return an error.

I am using this to fit over various unique data, so I want to avoid having to make a good initial guess.

Here is the base code:

```
def base(r,c,K):
    baseSag = c * r**2 / (1 + np.sqrt(1 - (K+1)*(c*r)**2 ))
    return baseSag

def base_residual(toFit,r,trueSag):
    c = toFit[0]
    K = toFit[1]

    arg = 1 - (K+1)*(c*r)**2    

    residual = base(r,c,K) - trueSag
    return residual


truesurf =  # Various input data
inital_guess = np.ones(2)*0.1 
# I have also tried better guesses of inital_guess = [-36,14.35] but I want to avoid doing that 

fit = least_squares(base_residual,inital_guess,
                    args = (r_points,truesurf),
                    verbose = 2,
                    gtol = None,
                    ftol = None)
```

I have tried adding a term that increases the residual if the sqrt argument is negative but that does not work.

```
def base_residual(toFit,r,trueSag):
    c = toFit[0]
    K = toFit[1]

    arg = 1 - (K+1)*(c*r)**2    

    isNeg = False
    for ele in arg:
        if ele < 0:
            isNeg = True
            return isNeg

    if isNeg:
        residual = arg**2
    else:
        residual = base(r,c,K) - trueSag

    return residual
```

How can I make the f(r) from becoming imaginary? AFAIK there isn't a way to constrain multiple variables to each other (i.e. constrain 1-(A+1)(B r)^2) > 0)

Additionally, I'd like to constrain K and c to be between certain values - not sure how to do that when I wrap the arguments inside base_rresidual. -90 < A < 90 and B > 0.1, B < - 0.1.  Is that possible?

Comment: `Additionally, I'd like to constrain K and c to be between certain values` Have you tried the `bounds` argument to `least_squares()`?

Comment: @NickODell I am able to bound A to be (-90,90) but I am unsure how to put a bound on B to be (-Inf,-0.1) or (0.1,+inf)

Comment: I don't think you can. However, you could call `least_squares()` twice, once with the first set of bounds, and once with the second set of bounds, and pick the one which best minimizes your objective.

Comment: `(-Inf,-0.1) or (0.1,+inf)` is possible with a quadratic constraint, but that's going to almost certainly encourage a local minimum.

Comment: Can you provide some real data?

Comment: It's quite unclear which of your variables are scalar or vector.

Answer (score 0):

One option among many is to send a set of linear and nonlinear constraints to COBYLA:

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint, LinearConstraint


def base(r: np.ndarray, c: float, K: float) -> np.ndarray:
    base_sag = c * r**2 / (1 + np.sqrt(1 - (K+1)*(c*r)**2))
    return base_sag


def base_residual(to_fit: np.ndarray, r: np.ndarray, true_sag: np.ndarray) -> float:
    residual = base(r, *to_fit) - true_sag
    return residual.dot(residual)


def argument_constr(to_fit: np.ndarray, r: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # The argument to the square root must be kept positive
    c, K = to_fit
    return 1 - (K + 1) * (c*r)**2


def c_constr(to_fit: np.ndarray) -> float:
    # c <= -0.1 or c >= 0.1
    c, K = to_fit
    return c**2


rand = default_rng(seed=0)
r_points = rand.uniform(low=-5e-3, high=5e-3, size=10)
true_surf = np.array([
    -3e-5, -9e-5, -4e-4, -4e-4,
    -1e-4, -3e-4, -2e-5, -9e-5,
    -3e-6, -3e-4])

fit = minimize(
    fun=base_residual, args=(r_points, true_surf),
    x0=(-30, 10),
    tol=1e-12,
    method='COBYLA',
    constraints=(
        LinearConstraint(
            A=(0, 1), lb=-90, ub=90,  # bounds on K
        ),
        NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=partial(argument_constr, r=r_points),
            lb=0, ub=np.inf,
        ),
        NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=c_constr, lb=0.1**2, ub=np.inf,
        ),
    ),
    options={'maxiter': 100_000},
)
assert fit.success, fit.message
print(fit)
```

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully.
 success: True
  status: 1
     fun: 5.135738007207637e-09
       x: [-2.786e+01  3.738e+01]
    nfev: 16799
   maxcv: 0.0
```